# Is there any option in loopback4 to use MongoDB document validation

Tags: mongodb, typescript, loopback4

I am using loopback4 with MongoDB.

I have a counter property in my model, and would like to do atomic operation to increment/decrement that counter.

My implementation now is using ExtendedOperators $inc to add or sub calculations.
But I found that despite of my jsonSchema set to minimum:0, the counter will be negative value when $inc:{counter:-1} at counter value 0.

I think I can use [Mongo Document Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) to set value range constraint, But I cant find the right way in repository code to do this.

Should I set it manually through Mongo Shell?
But how can I do error handling?

#### model

```
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    jsonSchema:{
      minimum:0,
    }
  })
  count: number;
```

#### controller

```
  async incrementCountById(
      @param.path.string('id') id: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    await this.userRepository.updateById(id, {$inc: {count: -1} });
  }
```

#### repository

```
const config = {
  allowExtendedOperators: true,
};
```

Any advice would be appreciated:)